# How do I add external FXML from another package to my tab with netbeans

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

The line to add the external FXML is not working, error:file not found

```
<TabPane prefHeight="702.0" prefWidth="1301.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" StackPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                <tabs>
                    <Tab text="Home">
                        <content>
                            <fx:include: source="com/zeal/cashrecord/order/ServiceOrder.fxml"/>
                        </content>
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: From [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements): The `<fx:include>` tag creates an object from FXML markup defined in another file. It is used as follows: `<fx:include source="filename"/>` where _filename_ is the name of the FXML file to include. Values that begin with a leading slash character are treated as relative to the classpath. Values with no leading slash are considered relative to the path of the current document. Did you try putting a slash before `com/zeal/...` ?